# Make Auto-complete widget scrollable in Ajax-Solr

Tags: jquery, solr

Im using ajax-solr. Because I have a large database, I get a large amount of suggestions in auto-complete widget . how do I implement a scrollbar there?
please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just add this style to the div that contains the autocomplete it will do the trick:
I think it's calld ui-autocomplete so if you just try to add this in a css file in your project:

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    height: 300px; //this must be fixed
    overflow: auto;
}
```

let me know if it works because I can't test it.